# How to make a toroidal array?

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to make a toroidal array for a Game of Life clone. How do I make it toroidal?

I've been thinking and the best solution I could think of, was just saying that the first row and column are equal to the last row and column.

Any other ideas?

EDIT: Maybe some people don't know what the Game of Life is? It's a small game with cells, in an array. These cells can be dead or alive and react to each other. Whenever a cell reaches the edge of my current solution, it bumps into a row/column of all dead cells. What I want to do now is, when a cell reaches the edge, it just pops up on the other side. (see the image below)

[image]

What my code looks like now:

```
#region check adjacent squares
        if (grid[x - 1,y - 1] == true)
            adjacentsquares++;              
        if (grid[x, y - 1] == true)
            adjacentsquares++;              
        if (grid[x + 1, y -1] == true)
            adjacentsquares++;              
            
        if (grid[x - 1, y] == true)
            adjacentsquares++;
        if (grid[x + 1, y] == true)
            adjacentsquares++;
            
        if (grid[x - 1, y + 1] == true)
            adjacentsquares++;
        if (grid[x, y + 1] == true)
            adjacentSquares +=1;
        if (grid[x + 1, y + 1] == true)
            adjacentSquares +=1;
#endregion
```

What I now need is that, whenever I want to check an adjacent cell (that would be out of bounds in a regular array) that it checks the one on the other side.

If I check position `[10,0]`. I need to check adjacent cells `[9, max]`, `[10, max]` and `[11, max]`.

Comment: You mean `maxX == 0` and `maxY == 0`. Otherwise if, only those two points are `== 0` it won't be toroidal.

Comment: What I meant with that piece of pseudocode is that the first row and column are equal to the last row and column. (will add this, might be more clear)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure I get your idea right, but why don't you create a method that encapsulates the access to your array and that accesses

```
array[x % max, y % max]
```

, where x and y are both ints passed to this method.

Explaining it a little further:
Say you have an array like `array[sizeX, sizeY]`. If you want to access the first position of your array, say `array[0, 0]`, you could do it like `array[0, 0]` or `array[sizeX, sizeY]`, since it wraps around both its X and Y dimensions (a toroidal array). Therefore, you could use the modulus operator, and always access your array like this:

```
array[desiredXPosition % sizeX, desiredYPosition % sizey]
```

Or better yet, create a method that does this automatically for you.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this a bit further? I'm still quite new to programming and don't really understand what you mean.

Comment: Let's see if I got this right. The cells on the outer rows/columns will have the same value when set in this way?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but the answer probably is yes. In a toroid implemented as an array[2, 2], for example, both array[0, 0] and array[2, 2] should refer to the same element, whether you are setting its value or reading its value. Likewise, array[3, 2] and array[1, 0] should refer to the same element, since in this case you are going around the toroid in both its "X axis" and its "Y axis". Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

Whenever you index the array, do so with a modulus: e.g.

```
  array[ x % size_x,  y % size_ y]
```

Note that I call them `size_x` and not `max_x`.  The maximum allowed x index is `size_x - 1`

Answer (score 0):

To make the access to an array [maxY,maxX] toroidal you should use modulu but adjust for the fact that C# & Java % modulo differs from math modulo (as it may return negative results).
The below returns the array value of a cell in bool[,] array, wrapping around the edges.

```
bool Exists(int i, int j) => cur[(i + maxY) % maxY, (j + maxX) % maxX];
```